# How do i obtain a trend for a daily time series?

Tags: time-series, forecasting

I have some a couple of years of data that tracks the number of tickets opened per day for an internal call center.  What is the best way to derive a trend for this data that accounts for the lower volume on weekends and company holidays?

I guess i'm looking for two things:

1. Retrospectively, how can i compare monthly volume year over year in a statistically meaningful way (accounting for trading day effects, etc...)?
2. Prospectively, how can i extrapolate from this data what future call volume will be so that i can set appropriate staffing levels?

I'm not sure what tool i'll be using for this yet.  If it can be done in Microsoft Excel, LibreOffice, or similar that would be ideal.

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/188597/forecasting-technique-for-daily-data-with-monthly-and-day-of-week-seasonality/188618#188618 would be of interest to you. There are solutions available in R but not in Excel.

Comment: You might also be interested in this thread http://demand-planning.com/2010/03/18/can-forecasting-help-me-staff-a-specific-hewlett-packard-call-center-at-1030-am-on-a-friday/