# ARIMA model facing problem in getting actual value after double differencing

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima, autocorrelation

I have data on temperature from 1969 to 2013 ([link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B04la1OAJTiHZ0MzMWlLTEdmOFU)).

I want to predict next year's temperature using an ARIMA model with finding correlation between predicted value and actual value. So I want to use data from 1969 to 2010 and then I want to predict for next 3 years. Furthermore, I want to compare it with the actual value and plot the graph and find accuracy.

But just to predict I gave all input from 1969 to 2013. I want to predict for the next year. As by seeing the ACF and PACF, I found that one difference is sufficient. My code is like this:

```
read   <- read.csv('G:/URMAY_CODE/day_temp_file.csv')
read_1 <- ts(read[,2], start=c(1969,1), frequency=365.25) 

ARIMA_FIT <- auto.arima(read_1, d=1, approximation=T, trace=T)
## Best model: ARIMA(3,1,1)
summary(ARIMA_FIT)
acf(residuals(ARIMA_FIT))
## I have plot ACF of the residuals form the arima(3,1,1) ##
plot(forecast(ARIMA_FIT), xlab="temperature", ylab="years")
## this shows me forecast like this
```

[image: result for forcasting]

I want something like zig-zag like but it is not giving that. I searched all the way through internet they are directly plotting the graph like this, but they are getting a zig-zag graph.

Sub Question: What is the role of `xreg` in `auto.arima()`, and how it is applicable to my code?

(I need help with the plotting as well as the comparison.)

Comment: To the extent I can follow this, it seems to be asking for code / code help, which is off topic here. If you have a statistical question about ARIMA, please edit to clarify.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there are two things going on here. (1) The forecasts in the graph are probably forecasts for a transformed version of the data - not the data in levels. (2) There is no periodic (zig-zag) pattern because you have not chosen a seasonal ARIMA model. Lastly, you use xreg if you have exogenous explanatory variables, but if you're basing your forecasts on the time-series properties of the data, you don't need this feature.

Comment: @RichardHardy i tried by applying frequency=365.25/7 but still it is showing the same graph  with title like this
`forcasts from ARIMA(3,1,1)(1,0,0)[52]`
i want graph like (zig-zag) with value .. so that i can find correlation with original value.

Comment: @gung yes i am asking for code solution but if you can suggest anything related to arima statistical you can .as i am new to this it would be very  helpful for me if you can share even a little knowledge that is must required before proceeding for code.
thank you!

Comment: I think it is still a matter of wrong frequency. `auto.arima` should definitely pick up this pattern as long as the relevant frequency is specified. What is the actual frequency of your data and how long a period does it span? (The lack of labels for the horizontal axis does not help.)

Comment: @GraemeWalsh 1) how can i convert it into original format so that i can get actual value and i can measure it with original one?
2) how can i make sure that i should go for seasonal,and in R what combination should i try `(seasonal = c(0,1,1))`? something like this ..what is first zero? what is second and third 1? what it means? because every site they are just showing seosonal equal to this.. but no one is showing why should i go for this? what it really means?
3) sorry but i dont have any idea about this **exogenous explanatory variables **
thank you for your reply ..

Comment: @RichardHardy i have also attached link of original file .if you can help me  something by seeing this..but as i read over some paper that if you are having daily data for many years frequency is either 365 or 365.25.
and as it is daily temperature file i dont think i should go for weekly basis .
but its ok ..if you can suggest anything than please go for it .. thank you so much

Comment: OK, my suggestion of using weekly frequency was stupid, I am embarrased. I see you have 45 years of daily data. Hmm. Since your seasonal period is so long, SARIMA is not really suitable; see Rob J. Hyndman ["Forecasting with long seasonal periods"](http://robjhyndman.com/hyndsight/longseasonality/) for an alternative approach with code examples. That should help.

Comment: Nice! If you have spare 15 minutes, you could write up an answer. That could be useful for someone visiting this thread in the future and wondering how it worked out.